# Ошибка "BaseActivity cannot be cast to Interface

Tags: java, android

Дело в том что, до этого времени, я интерфейсы реализовывал в `Activity`, значения методов задавал во `Fragment`. То есть, в `onAttach()` инициализировал, а потом где нужно вызвать метод интерфейса вызывал. Пример:

```
interface OnNumberChangeCallback{
    void onSuccess();
}
```

И Во `Fragment`:

```
OnNumberChangeCallback onNumberChangeCallback;

onAttach(Context context){
    onNumberChangeCallback = (OnNumberChangeCallback) context;
}
```

и т.д.

Дело в том, что я хочу инициализировать интерфейс в `BaseActivity`, и вызвать его метод. А во `Fragment` реализовать этот интерфейс.

Когда пытаюсь инициализировать в `onCreate` методе таким образом:

```
onNumberChangeCallback = (OnNumberChangeCallback) this;
```

то получаю ошибку:

> BaseActivity cannot be cast to OnNumberChangeCallback

**Вопрос**: Как правильно инициализировать интерфейс в `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, напишу, может кому поможет.

Реализуем наш интерфейс в `MyFragment`

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnNumberChangeCallback {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

И в `Activity` инициализируем, переопределив `onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment)`;

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OnNumberChangeCallback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

        if (fragment instanceof OnNumberChangeCallback) {
            callback = (OnNumberChangeCallback) fragment;
        }
    }
}
```

И дальше, вызываем метод `callback.onSuccess()`;

Comment: благо разобрались с callback'ами, а я не понимал как вам ответ написать =) зря Виктора минусанули, он эту идею и хотел донести до вас ...

Comment: "эту идею и хотел донести до вас" - одной строкой, что то не похоже)

Comment: дело в том, что у вас для фрагменотов начало в вопросе было положено правильно и то, что указал Виктор как раз было первым предположением, что вам не хватает, в следующий раз задавайте вопросы с большими примерами кода, чтобы более четкий можно было дать ответ

Comment: Мне кажется он не правильно понял. Специально я выделил жирным шрифтом слово "Вопрос", чтобы таких случаев не было. Не внимательно он прочел.

Comment: Его ответ был бы правильным, если бы спросил, "Как реализовать интерфейс в `Activity`"

Comment: тоже верно, но как по мне, вы слишком категоричны =)  главное, что вы нашли ответ =)

Comment: А что станет, когда ссылка на фрагмент "протухнет"? Я бы вам посоветовал завязаться на жизненный цикл фрагмента и передавать\обнулять ссылку на него в активити. Надежней будет.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, Не совсем понял, что значит "завязаться на жизненный цикл и передавать ссылку", можете разъяснить или пример привести?

Comment: В активити определите метод или интерфейс для задания ссылки на OnNumberChangeCallback, а в фрагменте, к примеру, в onStart() выставляете эту ссылку, а в onStop() обнуляете.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseActivity implements OnNumberChangeCallback
```

Comment: Я знаю как реализовывать. Вопрос: как инициализировать интерфейс в `Activity`?

Comment: @TITAN, раз вы пытаетесь в `onCreate` делать `onNumberChangeCallback = (OnNumberChangeCallback) this;` и не получается, то это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос.